# I can't get my Bootstrap columns expand with the same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

**First, I know this question has been asked several times, and I tried all the solutions I found. That's why I'm asking it again.**

The Bootstrap grid I'm working with has max-width: 1000px. At this size, the three columns are perfectly the same height. The problem is when the screen gets smaller and duo to the different number of characters they have, they don't expand with the same height.

What have I tried so far? display: table; flexbox; row-eq-height; matchheight.js.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPQjjp try resize the browser window and you can see one column gets bigger than the other depending on the window size.

```
<div class="feature1">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="col-sm-12 well feature1-box">Text goes here</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="col-sm-12 well feature1-box">Text goes here</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><div class="col-sm-12 well feature1-box">Text goes here</div></div>
      </div>
```

The extra columns "col-sm-12" is a trick I learned here in order to give a white space between the three main columns.

CSS

```
.feature1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a codepen or jsfiddle to let us see exactly what code you have?

Comment: @JackMoody sure https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwOmpP

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. Do you want your boxes to have the same height no matter how many words are in the boxes?

Comment: @JackMoody Yes, that's what I want. Like in a table. Otherwise I'll have to set fixed heights for the various screen sizes, but I don't want that.

Comment: It looks like the boxes are the same size in the codepen when resizing. Maybe the images are different sizes so I can't tell the difference.

Comment: @JackMoody Acess this other link here please and try resize the browser window, you'll see what I'm talking about https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPQjjp

Comment: I had the same issue you had a few years ago. I ended up writing a bit of javascript/jQuery that checked the heights of the divs and made them the same height as the longest div. So that is one solution. But we do have css-grids now. That would be perfect for your purposes, but you would have to abandon the bootstrap grid approach and use css-grids all the way.

Answer (score 0):

A guy from the Dreamwaver forum on adobe.com, helped me with this. This is literally the only solution that worked.

In my case, that's the CSS I should use:

```
.feature1 {

display: flex;

flex-wrap: wrap;

margin-left: auto;

margin-right: auto;

max-width: 1000px;

}

.col-sm-4 {

display: flex;

}

.well {

flex: 1;

}

.well h3 {

text-align: center;

}

.well figure {

text-align: center;

}
```